# How to correctly config maven-assembly to create one fat jar for multi-module project?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

How to config multi-module project in Maven assembly to create one fat jar with all dependencies and chosen entrypoint?

I have multi-module project

**main(parent) pom**

```
<artifactId>parentModule</artifactId>
<groupId>com.myapps</groupId>
[...]
<modules>
   <module>childModule1</module>
   <module>childModule2</module>
</modules>
```

**child pom 1**

```
<artifactId>childModule1</artifactId>
<groupId>com.myapps</groupId>
[...]
<parent>
  <artifactId>parentModule</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.myapps</groupId>
</parent>
```

**child pom 2 (with entry point com.myapps.application.App ,and depends on childModule1)**

```
<artifactId>childModule2</artifactId>
<groupId>com.myapps</groupId>
[...]
<parent>
  <artifactId>parentModule</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.myapps</groupId>
</parent>
[...]
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <artifactId>childModule1</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.myapps</groupId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What config I have to add to my poms(assembly plugin tag) and my assembly.xml to create one fat jar with all needed dependencies(including childModule1) running from entrypoint(which is in childModule2)?

My plugin tag in main(parent) pom includes:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                       <descriptor>assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.myapps.application.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And assembly.xml consists of "*filesets*" tags, and tag "*format*".

What additional config I have to add to my poms or assembly config xml, to create one full-operational fat jar as a result? For now it makes distributive with files successfully but fails to create jar with an error - "***archive can not be empty***". I suppose that it makes by "*moduleset*" tags in assembly, I have read docs, but cant understand how to do it.

UPD
Do I need to create plugin tag in parentmodule with descriptor "assembly/assembly.xml"(with fileset instructions) and separate plugin tag in childmodule2 with descriptor "jar-with-dependencies"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways, but I have some time ago distilled this into a step-by-step approach in: https://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/packaging-a-multimodule-maven-spring-app-in-a-standalone-jar/

However, there are multiple other ways to do so, which might be a bit more modern. For example, some use `maven-shade-plugin`, some can use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (I currently use that to embed my `jetty` inside), but there you have a bit less control over what's going on, as they do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

## If you still wanna use maven-assembly-plugin

If you are stuck with having to use the `maven-assembly-plugin`, then you can combine it with:

- `maven-jar-plugin`
- and `maven-dependency-plugin`

Comment: I deal with scala, and used maven-jar-plugin plugin before, but now I just need to pack this jar(maven-jar-plugin do it correctly for me) into zip with some additional files. This task looks like trivial, but i have surprised that it is not for me)

Comment: I thought of how to make assembly use artifact which maven jar made, but have not resolve it yet...

Comment: Consider using the `maven-dependency-plugin` as well, so it can give you the proper hierarchy of the dependencies.

Comment: You write that your assembly use jar artifact (step3 on your article). But how to be sure that assembly will wait for maven-jar plugin to do its work?

Comment: The goals/phases are done in a specific order, so it's always executed in the proper order.

Comment: I thought that jar plugin executes on package phase as an assembly one.

Comment: Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: I have just made "mvn package assembly:single" instead of "mvn package" and it helped me, I do not know why plugin not started at package phase...

Comment: For now have refactored project and made it as I want. The key point is that you need to make special submodule for assembly plugin and to configure it in the pom of its module. This variant work perfect.